# get list of tables in database using boto3

Tags: python-3.x, boto3, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I’m trying to get a list of the tables from a database in my aws data catalog.  I’m trying to use boto3.  I’m running the code below on aws, in a sagemaker notebook.  It runs forever (like over 30 minutes) and doesn’t return any results.  The test_db only has 4 tables in it.  My goal is to run similar code as part of an aws glue etl job, that I would run in an edited aws etl job script.  Does anyone see what the issue might be or suggest how to do this?

code:

```
import boto3
from pprint import pprint

glue = boto3.client('glue', region_name='us-east-2')

response = glue.get_tables(
    DatabaseName=‘test_db’
)

print(pprint(response['TableList']))
```

Comment: are the API calls hitting AWS Service? You can verify this by looking at the CloudTrails event history for GetTables API calls. Also, can you verify whether the SageMaker notebook has internet access?

Answer (score 6):

```
db = session.resource('dynamodb', region_name="us-east-2")
tables = list(db.tables.all())
print(tables)
```

resource
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/dynamodb.html